# Troublesoot ruby require

Tags: ruby, require

Ruby require only works for me with gems not with code that I have written.  I'm not sure what it is that I am doing wrong.

**This works**

```
require "test-unit"
require "require "C:\\Users\\zreichert\\workspace\\FalconQA\\PageObjects\\Users\\user.rb"
```

**This doesn't work**

```
require "Users/user"
require "Users\user"
require "Users/user.rb"
require "Users\user.rb"
require_relative "Users/user"
require_relative "Users\user"
require_relative "Users/user.rb"
require_relative "Users\user.rb"
```

The script that I am running is located in - C:/Users/zreichert/workspace/FalconQA/testCases

I have tried to change directories before require like this

```
Dir.chdir "C:/Users/zreichert/workspace/FalconQA/testCases"
```

All errors look something like this

c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- Users/user (LoadError)
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from C:/Users/zreichert/workspace/FalconQA/testCases/FAL001.rb:14:in `

Comment: try `require "./Users/user"`

Comment: @slivu Thanks that worked, please convert to answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Anything looking like `"Users\user"` will fail because of how escaped characters are interpreted in double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
require "./Users/user"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
require_relative '../PageObjects/Users/user.rb'
```

Slash is better than two backslashes, because it works in both Windows and Linux/MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on [Roozbeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1669634/roozbeh)'s answer slightly, `require_relative` allows you to load files relative to the location of the file containing the `require_relative` so doing a `chdir` will not have any effect on this.

From what you've said in the question, the relative path from FAL001.rb to user.rb is

```
../PageObjects/Users/user.rb
```

i.e. up one level and then down into PageObjects/Users, hence

```
require_relative '../PageObjects/Users/user.rb'
```

Comment: This makes complete sense to me but when I try this I get:C:/Users/zreichert/workspace/FalconQA/testCases/FAL001.rb:4:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- C:/Users/zreichert/workspace/FalconQA/testCases/Users/userdata.rb (LoadError)
 from C:/Users/zreichert/workspace/FalconQA/testCases/FAL001.rb:4:in `<main>'  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Figured out my mistake, disregard last comment.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a mental-safety tip, anything looking like `"Users\user"` will fail because of how escaped characters are interpreted in double-quoted strings.

Instead, use single-quotes for your `require` parameter to preserve your sanity:

```
require 'foo'
```

or

```
require './relative/path/to/foo'
require '../relative/path/to/bar'
```